# git pre-push hook fails to push everything

Tags: git, shell, repository, githooks

I need to change a set of files before pushing them to repo...
Approach I'm using works in a way that it leaves commit in the loop 'un-pushed'
so i need to manually push again with -forced tags..

```
for i in files; do
   edit $i
   git add $i
   git commit  -o $i -n -m "Updated ..."
   git tag $TAG -f
done

exit 0
```

Tried to ammend previous commits, but failed on this one as well.
Is there a way this would push everything as i would expect:

> if pre-push exits with 0, files are pushed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I've solved it by utilizing aliases:

```
git config --global alias.t '!/path/to/above/script'
```